# Calling two stored procedures in the same TransactionScope()

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two stored procedures and calling both of them in the same TransactionScope as follows.

- The first - `SPInsert()` - inserts a new row into Table A
- The second - `SPUpdate()` - updates the recently inserted row in the Table A

My question is, even though I have put a break point before the second stored procedure is getting called, I am unable to see the first stored procedure's row in the table, until the `TransactionScope` is completed.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    // Call and execute stored procedure 1
    SPInsert();

    // Call and execute stored procedure 2
    SPUpdate();

    transactionScope.Complete();
}
```

**In detail:**

I put a break point on SPUpdate, just right after the SPInsert, want to check on SQL to see whether or not row is being inserted, but when I run the query to check table, it keeps executing, never stops. It seems that table is not accessible at that moment. Then how would I check whether or not row is being inserted before second store procedure is getting called

Comment: My 2 cents on this, is that, the default isolation level for `TransactionScope` is `serializable` that blocks the table until the transaction is complete...that's why you are not able to check the changes.

Comment: So you put your breakpoint on `SPInsert()`? If that's the case, it is not executing `SPInsert()` which would make sense that you don't see the row. Move the breakpoint to `SPUpdate()`.

Comment: Does your stored procedure explicitly commit the insert?  Are you trying to see the row WITH (NOLOCK)?  If not, you will not see the commit until the transaction is closed.  That is when an implicit commit is done.

Comment: I put a break point on SPUpdate, just right after the SPInsert, want to check on SQL to see whether or not row is being inserted, but when I run the query to check table, it keeps executing, never stops. It seems that table is not accessible at that moment. Then how would I check whether or not row is being inserted before second store procedure is getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are in a transaction, by design and by default, SQL Server wont show you any uncommitted operations if you connect using a different session. This is why you cannot see uncommitted operations.

Comment: That means, should I move the second store procedure out of transaction scope section?

Comment: NO, just run your test query using with(NOLOCK). This is about the ONLY time I would suggest using that hint. But it will allow you to read uncommitted transactions.

Comment: Could you please illustrate? NOLOCK?

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE WITH NOLOCK